# Extracting discontinuous set of rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing 100 rows. It looks something like this

```
id_number  Name Age Salary
00001       Alice 50 6.2234
00002       John  29 9.1
.
.
.
00098       Susan 36 11.58
00099       Remy  50 3.7
00100       Walter 50 5.52
```

From this dataframe, I want to extract the rows corresponding to individuals whose ID numbers do NOT lie between 11 and 20. I want rows 0 to 9, and 20 to 99.

`df.iloc` allows extracting a continuous set of rows, like 20 to 99, but not 0 to 9 and 20 to 99 in the same go.
I also tried `df[(df['id_number'] >= 20) & (df['id_number'] < 10)]` but that returns an empty dataframe.

Is there a straightforward way to do this, that does not require doing two separate extractions and their concatenation?

Comment: Does `df[df['id_number'] => 20]` give the expected result?

Comment: what is `dtype` of `id_number` column.

Comment: what you wanted to do was probably: `df[(df['id_number'] => 20) | (df['id_number'] < 10)]`

Comment: @Keldorn => was a typo. It should be ```>=```, which does give the expected result.

Comment: @quest ```int64```

Comment: @aasthas, just saw this. See my attempt

Answer (score 0):

drop sliced index is what you need

in this case we are slicing 11 through to 20

Data

```
df=pd.Series(np.arange(1,101))
df
```

drop slice

```
df.drop(df.loc[11:20].index, inplace=True)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work (suggested by @FarhoodET):

```
df[(df['id_number'] => 20) | (df['id_number'] < 10)]
```